# Reading json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Below is the JSON object I have in my JavaScript:

```
[{"hero title":"dsksklj","hero title2":"lsjdlk","hero text":"skjvls"}]
```

How can I iterate through it and save name and values in different variables?

Comment: there is something called `for` then you use it like `for(var i=0;i<myVar.length;i++){ var[i]["hero title"]; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]["hero text"]);
}
```

Comment: so the key elements will be in other varaible like keys={hero text,hero title, hero title2}. then..?